# I am using bootstrap how do I change the color of this navbar by using my css file?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap and I want to change the color of the navbar but I am unable to do it.

Here is the html code for the nav bar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TweetyBird</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Search by Tweet <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Twitter Bot</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">To be added</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Here is what I put in my CSS file but the color is still not changing. What do I need to do to be able to change the color?

```
.navbar{
 background-color: darkslategray;
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to add an important declaration. Just add your file after the bootstrap files. Use equal or greater specificity in your selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that, but you have to add !important to overwrite current value.

```
.navbar{
    background-color: darkslategray!important;
}
```

or use the solution from HuserB1989(Comments)

```
html .navbar{
    background-color: darkslategray;
}
```

Comment: Note that there needs to be a space between `darkslategray` and `!important`.

Comment: `!important` should be used only in the worst case. Better practice to make the selector more specific.

Comment: @HuserB1989 Yeah you are totally right, thats even better. TY :)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to make your selector more specific, like in the example below:

```
.myNavBar {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/example](https://jsfiddle.net/HuserB8927/k6wvr7ox/)